# how to make jquery update html on after function?

Tags: jquery, html

After adding html to a document with the jquery after() function, how do you make the html page maintain the added html when the browser gets refreshed?

Comment: If it maintained its content, then it wouldn't be refreshed.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? If you give us more information about the actual requirement, perhaps we can make suggestion on how to solve it.

Comment: have a user submit a form. if they press a button, then a new form input field gets added with the after() function.

Comment: @SamAdams why do you want the form field there if the user hits the refresh button.  seems to me that it's actually a better choice to re-render the page as it was originally.  if you're concerned that they may lose work, why not use an unload handler to detect if they are navigating away from a changed page and allow them to abort if they really want to keep the changes.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do that, since, on a refresh, the page is rendered according to the `.html` file (or `.php` etc.).

What you want would require you to write the changes on the file at your server, which of course, jquery (Javascript) cannot do since it runs client-side.

Answer (score 2):

You must call `html()` again on next page loading. If you need to keep some data between visits, you can use web storage for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try, HTML 5 Storage API.

```
// store your new html, after your jquery.after

localStorage.setItem('htmlVal', 'your New HTML');
```

then, on document.ready...you can append it...

like,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var myVar = localStorage.getItem('htmlVal');
if(myVar != ''){
    $("#yourlement").after(myVar);
}

});
```

.. doesn't make practical sense, but, i think, solves your requirement.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. When you refresh the page, the browser gets a completely new page from the server, which just happens to be the same as the current one.

You have to recreate the elements after the new page has loaded, so you have to send along enough information to the new page, so that your scripts knows what to do after the page has loaded.